# Error executing two functions at the same time in typescript (VS Code)

Tags: typescript, function, loops, visual-studio-code

I have two functions which are hard to execute, including *"for"* loops with querys to SQL.

**When I execute one and I comment the other, it works perfectly.** The problem comes when I try to execute both at the same time. It doesn´t matter if I add a *"setTimeout"* or how long I set it, it only executes the one I have set to be done first. The error is:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Invalid object name
> 'TableOfDataBase'.

Often I get that error several times mentioning the name of different tables of the database.

A sample of code:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.comun();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.comun2();
    }, 5000);
  } // These are the two functions I´m talking about



comun() {
    this.getPlanificacion2();
    this.getIdAlfabetico();
    this.getPuestos();
    setTimeout(() => {

      for (let i = 0; i < this.id_alfabetico.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.puestos.length; j++) {
          this.ipService.getIp(this.puestos[j]['nombre']).subscribe(
            res => {
              if (res != null && res != undefined && res != "") {
                if (res[0]['ip2'] == null) {
                  this.cuentaAsientosService.getComun(this.id_alfabetico[i], this.puestos[j]['nombre'], res[0]['ip'], res[0]['etiqueta']).subscribe(
                    res => {
                      if (res['numero'] != 0) {
                        console.log(`A - Número de ${res['nombreTrabajador']} en el puesto ${res['puesto']}: ${res['numero']}`)
    
                      }

                    },
                    err => {
                      console.log(err)
                    }
                  )
                }                    
              }
            }
          )
        }
      }
    }, 500);
  }



comun2() {
    
    this.getPlanificacion2();
    this.getIdAlfabetico2();
    this.getPuestos2();
    setTimeout(() => {

      for (let i = 0; i < this.id_alfabetico2.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.puestos2.length; j++) {
          this.ipService.getIp(this.puestos2[j]['nombre']).subscribe(
            res => {

              if (res != null && res != undefined && res != "") {
                if (res[0]['ip2'] != null) {

                  this.referenciasComun2(res, this.id_alfabetico2[i], this.puestos2[j]['id_puesto'])
                }
              }
            }
          )
        }
      }
    }, 500);
  }
```

The first "for" loop takes the name of the people from an array and the second the place where can be this person. It goes to the database with this information and makes a query. Finally it shows in the console amount of work of this person and where has been done. It´s a loop, so in the end I see the work of everybody.
The second funtion (comun2) is very similar, but uses different information.

The thing is, if comment "comun" in "ngOnInit", "comun2" works perfectly and viceversa, do you know how can I have both working properly?

If you need to know anything else, just ask me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] of the code causing the issue. Hint: There is no such thing as code that executes "at the same time" in JavaScript, unless you're using workers or a server-side implementation of JavaScript that allows for multithreading.

Comment: Well, at least we would need to see some code ...

Comment: But judging from your error message, you are executing an sql query and are trying to access a table that doesn't exist ... which is throwing an error and thus dropping out of the current codeblock ...

Comment: @HereticMonkey you´re right, I´ve edited with some code. About "at the same time" I wanted to say to use both, as I say in my edit, one works if I comment the other but I don´t want to comment anyone.

Comment: @derpirscher I´ve edited with some code. Despite it looks like this, the error can´t be to be trying to access to a table that doesn´t exist, due to it works when I don´t use the other. It´s very confusing.

Comment: I think neither `comun` nor `comun2` are the problem. The don't have to do anything with the database. I suppose the problem lies in `getIp` or `getComun` which may do something to the database connection, that makes subsequent calls fail.

Comment: @derpirscher getIp and getComun make "get" querys ("select" execute) to the database, do you think it could cause a fail? I´m adding the function "comun2", maybe it can help.

Comment: Please add the database related code, because obviously something is failing with your connection to the database ...

Comment: @derpirscher you were right! The error was in the query, I forgot to type "use NameOfDatabase" before the select, so it couldn´t find the tables when it changed the database it was reading. It´s quite obvius but I am using these querys since some months ago and I didn´t think the problem was there. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Chesco1997 That makes me wonder how this even worked in the first place ...

Comment: @derpirscher when I do the connection to SQLServer I point to the database "DB1", which is the database I use in the functions getPlanificacion, getIdAlfabetico and getPuestos. Later getComun uses the database "DB2" and here I already had "USE DB2". When comun2 is executed it is still pointing to DB2, so the functions of the beginning can´t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the querys, I forgot to type "USE NameOfDatabase" before the SELECT, so it couldn´t find the tables when it changed the database it was reading.

```
public async getIps (req: Request, res: Response) {
    const lectura = await pool.query(`

    USE NameOfDatabase;              <-- Here!
    SELECT * FROM NameOfTable`);

    console.log(lectura.recordset);
    res.json(lectura.recordset);
}
```

I know it´s very obvius but I have been using these querys since some months ago and I didn´t think the problem was there.